# How to test the Optionality of a String?

Tags: swift, option-type

I have two different scenarios where I need to test the "optionality" of an optional type. I have not been able to figure how to *explicitly* test if the variable is a `.None` or a `.Some` other than with an unwieldy switch statement.  How can I test for `Someness` with an `if` statement?

#### Scenario 1

I am writing an address formatter and my inputs are a number of String? types. In this example a simple test for `(str != nil)` will work. However, since my other need is when dealing with a 'double optional' and a nil test can't distinguish between `.Some(.None)` and `.None` a solution to this problem will solve that problem too.

Here's a version that works using a `switch`

```
let address1:String? = "123 Main St"
let address2:String? = nil
let apt:String? = "101"

let components = [address1, address2, apt].filter( { (c) -> Bool in
    switch c {
    case .Some: return true
    case .None: return false
    }
}).map { return $0! } //Had to map because casting directly to [String] crashes
print(", ".join(components)) //"123 Main St, 101"
```

What's I'd like to see is something like with an `if`:

```
let nice = ["123 Main St", nil, "303"].filter { (c) -> Bool in
    return (c == .Some)
}
print(", ".join(nice))
```

#### Scenario 2

This is where a nil test won't work. If something is a String?? it can be any of `.None`, `.Some(.None)`, or `.Some(.Some(String))`. In my case, the variable is carrying the recordID from an api call which might either be missing entirely (`.None`), a value (`.Some(.Some("ABDEFG")`), or explicitly `NULL` (`.Some(.None)`).

```
let teamNoneNone: String?? = .None
let teamSomeNone: String?? = .Some(.None)
let teamSomeSome: String?? = "My favorite local sportsball team"

if teamNoneNone == nil {
    print("teamNoneNone is nil but is it .None? We don't know!") //prints
} else {
    print("teamNoneNone is not nil")    
}

if teamSomeNone == nil {
    print("teamSomeNone is nil")
} else {
    print("teamSomeNone is not nil but is it .Some(.None)? We don't know!") //prints
}

if teamSomeSome == nil {
    print("teamSomeSome is nil but is it .None? We don't know!")
} else {
    print("teamSomeSome is not nil but is it .Some(.None) or .Some(.Some())? We don't know!") //prints
}
```

Via another SO post I found a workaround like this, but it's not very clear what's happening to a casual reader:

```
if let team: String? = teamSomeNone {
    print("teamSomeNone is Some(.None)") //prints
} else {
    print("teamSomeNone is .Some(.Some())")
}
```

Comment: Option types are often better handled using a switch/case construct imo. Every option class I've ever seen though has an `isNone`/`isSome` method. If not, you could always define such a function using a switch.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, do you have any reference for this isNone/isSome method? I've searched Apple's docs, SwiftDoc.org, and tried it in the runtime and found nothing.  If it exists, that would be exactly what I am looking for, but it doesn't appear to.

Comment: Sorry, I was saying that all the languages that I know that have Option types (Haskell, Scala, Java) have a tester method; it would be odd if Swift didn't (I don't know Swift). Did you try evaluating the option as a Boolean? (`if (aMaybeObj)`)

Comment: Just ran across this blog post by David Owens II addressing this issue that handles it rather well, IMHO. http://owensd.io/2015/05/12/optionals-if-let.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if let` tests if a value is `.None`, and if it isn’t, it unwraps it and binds it to a local variable within an if statement.

Using switch with `.Some` and `.None` is really a secondary way of handling optionals, if `if let` doesn’t cut it.  But it almost always does, especially now you can do multiple `if let`s in a single statement, following the latest release of Swift 1.2 to production.

Wanting to filter out the nils in a collection is a common-enough task that Haskell has a standard function for it, called `catMaybe`.  Here’s a version, which I’ll call `catSome`, that would do the trick in Swift:

```
func catSome<T>(source: [T?]) -> [T] {
    var result: [T] = []
    // iterate over the values
    for maybe in source {
        // if this value isn’t nil, unwrap it
        if let value = maybe {
            // and append it to the array
            result.append(value)
        }
    }
    return result
}

let someStrings: [String?] = ["123 Main St", nil, "101"]

catSome(someStrings)  // returns ["123 Main St", "101"]
```

Doubly-wrapped optionals are a bit of a pain, so the best solution is to avoid them in the first place – often, via use of optional chaining or `flatMap`.

But if you do find yourself with some, and all you care about is the inner value, you can unwrap them using a double `if let`:

```
// later parts of the let can rely on the earlier
if let outer = teamSomeSome, teamName = outer {
    println("Fully unwrapped team is \(teamName)")
}
```

If you want to explicitly know if a double-optional has an inner `nil` inside an outer value, but isn’t `nil` itself, you can use `if let` with a `where` clause:

```
if let teamSomeMaybe = teamSomeNone where teamSomeMaybe == nil {
    // this will be executed only if it was .Some(.None)
    println("SomeNone")
}
```

The `where` clause is an extra conditional that can be applied to the unwrapped value.

Comment: Thanks for a very complete answer!  I just upgraded my project to Swift 1.2 yesterday so I hadn't used the `where` clause before.  That's not as clear as I'd like to see but definitely a great improvement over what I had.  If nobody comes up with something clearer I'll accept this answer.